# Saving state of execution of redis or restoring after a shutdown (Not the database but redis data)

Tags: redis

I am faced with the scenario that I need to restore the state of redis exec after a shutdown. I am not talking about database persistence but rather redis persistence.
The point of interest here is that I need to restore the master and slave information after a shutdown. i.e. which database is master and which is slave.
Is such a thing possible in redis ?
Or something needs to be done programatically?

Comment: What mode of Redis do you use? Cluster mode or sentinel?

Comment: None of them actually. Just normal redis that on runtime becomes a replica of another database.